# How can we monitor internal or external webservices?

Tags: monitoring, performance, network-monitoring

We have Web Performance monitoring third party tool. We are using New Relic.

However, we are not able to monitor either Internal or External Web services.

In an assumption, if the web service goes unresponsive, we need to get the alert immediately, before it drops down the production.

How can we monitor internal or external web services? Is there a third party tool available to monitor the web services?

Note: Web services are not direct user interacting portal. Application invokes the methods in web service to exchange data. There were some scenarios, we faced web service became idle or unresponsive. This immediately affected the Production. In our understanding New Relic supports only interactive web applications.

Comment: This should be possible with new relic. Why does it not work according to you?

Comment: @goofyui how does a webservice answering a GET/POST request can't be tested by newrelic ? All monitoring solutions handle sending request and validating the response along with alerting on request time. For more information, talk to your New Relic Sale's representative.

Comment: @Tensibai, Thank you for the explaination. So, In my understanding  - we can  use New Relic for both internal and external ( client's ) webservices to track their responsiveness

Comment: As far as I know yes, you may have to include nr scripts in your web services or to deploy an agent for internal services tests, but again, a ne sales representative will be more authoritative to address your problem in my opinion:)

Comment: Please explain what you would like to achieve. E.g: What is currently not working? What did you try to solve the issue? What kind of impediments occur? What did you find on the internet and why did the results not solve the issue? Please edit the Q&A.

Comment: Assumption :- Either a Webservice , RestAPI - When the service goes unresponsive. Meaning, Service become idle. This might happen on various reasons. One of the possible scenario is, if the server consumes too much memory, it interrupts the hosted services. Question :- How to set an alert or monitor , when a service goes unresponsive.  Going unresponsive doesn't mean that service was shutdown.